# PyCharm undo add to VCS (svn)

Tags: svn, version-control, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2019.1.3 and have accidentally added a big number of files to version control / svn (amongst other files which I wanted to add) within the program, but I have not committed the changes yet.

Is there a way to undo the add to SVN (but to keep the local files of course)? Maybe via moving the files to a different location (so that they seem deleted) and then moving them back?

Comment: It seems the SVN revert option can be used before commit within PyCharm, which removes the files from versioning.

Answer (score 0):

I know the basic version of undoing staged file.
From Terminal

```
git checkout <file_name>
git reset <file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the SVN revert option can be used before commit within PyCharm, which removes the files from versioning.